# How to close all tasks and processes correctly when window is closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I am creating application with feature that open new window inside my application and starting additional processes and tasks inside them. I am realized that when we trying open and close window to often (less than one second per reopening) some tasks wasn't canceled and some processes as I wanted.

For canceling tasks and processes I use `CancellationTokenSource`, `CancellationToken` which one I `Cancel()` and `Dispose()` in `Window.Closed [Event]`.

But if I will reopening my window too often its say me that Task was canceled or disposed.

So, How I can start my Tasks in Window constructor and closed correctly them when window closing?

Code:

```
MyAdditionalWindowClass
{
    private CancellationTokenSource source;
    private CancellationToken token;
    private Process process;

    MyAdditionalWindowClass()
    {
         source = new CancellationTokenSource();
         token = source.Token;
         Start();
         thiswindow.Closed += (sender, e) => { process?.Kill(); process?.Close(); source.Cancel(); source.Dispose(); };
    }
    private async void Start()
    {
         await Task.Run(ToDoSomething), token);
         //and other code after await
    }
    private void ToDoSomething()
    {
         //creating process, start him, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The mistake you make is; passing the source.Token to that task won't be used inside the task. Passing a cancellationtoken to a task.run prevents the task from starting when it was canceled before the task.run. You need to check the source.IsCanceled property inside the ToDoSomething.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should ask all components to close nicely when the user exits an application. Usually done by calling the Dispose method on any components that is disposable.

It the component has some background task it should tell this task to exit when it is disposed, for example by using a cancellation token, but there are other methods, like completing a blocking queue. Ideally you should use [IAsyncDispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable.disposeasync?view=net-6.0) since that lets your dispose method return the task, so the caller can await it. If that is not available you need to decide if you can safely wait for the task, or if it is better to return before you are certain the background task has completed.

If the background task involves any IO you *should* wait for it to complete, otherwise you risk aborting in the middle of a write. If there is no IO involved, waiting is less important since the OS will cleanup the memory anyway.